# Writing method without declaring type of that

Tags: c#, methods

in some documentation i saw some methods that were written without declaring type of that(e.g void,string,int,etc...). like this:

```
public ActorRecord()
    {
        ActorMovies = new List<MovieActorRecord>();
    }
```

or

```
    private readonly ITaxonomyService _taxonomyService;
    private readonly IContentManager _contentManager;

    public MovieFeatureEventHandler(ITaxonomyService taxonomyService, IContentManager  contentManager)
    {
        _taxonomyService = taxonomyService;
        _contentManager = contentManager;
    }
```

what does these methods do.
what is diffrence between | public ActorRecord() and public void/string ActorRecord() | ?

Answer (score 4):

You could have noticed that those methods also have the exact same name as the class (or struct) that they are in.

They are called [constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ace5hbzh.aspx).

Q: what is diffrence between `public ActorRecord()` and public `void ActorRecord()`  ?

A: Inside a `class ActorRecord {}`, the first is a constructor and the second is a syntax error.

Comment: oh, yes their class name are same name. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The methods in questions are called constructors. When you create a new instance of an object the code inside the constructor method is called to 'set up' the object in question.

For example

```
Public Class Thing
{
   private int _amount;

    public Thing()
    {
       _amount = 5;
    }
}
```

If I call this code:

```
var thing = new Thing();
```

Then a will get a new Thing with an _amount variable of '5'

If you add the void than it will become a normal method and be called like other methods:

```
thing.Thing()
```

Comment: However, it is not allowed for a method (which is not a constructor) to have the exact same name as the class (or struct) in which it is declared.